# Property Binding to Dependency property in Custom control not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have created a custom control with DependencyProperty called “ItemsPerPage”. I have used that custom control in a window. Now if I am assigning value directly to ItemsPerPage property then it is working but if I am binding it with property defined in window then it is not working.

**Declaration of Custom Control.**

```
public class SmartDataGrid : DataGrid
{

    public SmartDataGrid()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SmartDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SmartDataGrid)));
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsPerPageProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsPerPage", typeof(Int32),
           typeof(SmartDataGrid)
           , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnItemsPerPageChanged, CoerceTextProperty, true, UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged));

    public Int32 ItemsPerPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (Int32)GetValue(ItemsPerPageProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsPerPageProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnItemsPerPageChanged(DependencyObject defectImageControl, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var control = (SmartDataGrid)defectImageControl;
        control.callmyInstanceMethod(eventArgs);
    }

    private static object CoerceTextProperty(DependencyObject d, object value)
    {
        return value ?? 0;
    }
    private void callmyInstanceMethod(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsPerPage = (Int32)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

**Now I have created a New WPF project and in Window1 I have used this custom control as below.**

```
<Grid>
        <sg:SmartDataGrid ItemsPerPage="{Binding ipp}"></sg:SmartDataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Here sg: is a namespace declared to add reference of custom control project.And In .cs file of Window1 I have declared a property.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    int _ipp;
    public int ipp
    { get { return _ipp; } set { _ipp = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }

    public Window1()
    {
        ipp = 30;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**But value 30 is not assigning to ItemsPerPage property. It is showing 0 always.
If I am assigning 30 directly `ItemsPerPage="30"`. Then it is working.**

Comment: Each change of a property has to be **notified** to get the binding working. There is no magic around here. A normal class (ViewModel, Model, ...) should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and classes derived from DependencyObject should use a DependencyProperty (Window is derived from DependencyObject)

Comment: I have implemented NotifyPropertyChanged but still it is not working

Comment: @SirRufo, I think DataGrid is also derived from DepedencyObject.

Comment: Please note that your OnItemsPerPageChanged callback is pointless. There is no need to set `ItemsPerPage = (Int32)e.NewValue;` because it already has that value. The callback is meant to perform actions after a property value has been changed.

Comment: Yes I know that there are some extra implementation. But i was trying different options to let it work. I will remove extra work.

Comment: Note also that if the `ipp` property value never changes during runtime, it is pointless to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for it. Just assign a value before InitializeComponent is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think author of the OP wants to set datacontext to window.
You need to bind your control to Window's property like that:

```
ItemsPerPage="{Binding Path=ipp,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                         AncestorType=Window}}"
```

ipp should Notify Property Changed:

```
int _ipp;
public int ipp
{ 
   get=>_ipp;
   set{
        if (value!=_ipp)
        {
           _ipp=value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ipp));
        }
   }
}
void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
}


public Window1()
{
     ipp = 30;
     InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Although it is working, a class derived from DependencyObject should use a DependencyProperty

Comment: @Access Denied, Question updated, I have implemented NotifyPropertyChanged  but still it is not working .And also i have assigned value to ipp before initialization so it should work without NotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @AccessDenied your solution worked and marked as the solution suits perfect to my need. I do not want to implement datacontext.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is, that you did not specify the `DataContext` of the Window.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public int ipp { get; set; }
    public Window1()
    {
        ipp = 30;
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: @maulikkansara You should consider to have a ViewModel for your View and use that ViewModel as the DataContext for binding. MVVM is **the pattern** which was in mind when developing WPF.

Comment: agree.But i was preparing a demo project to test Custom control and just ignored to implement MVVM in demo project. That was my biggest mistake.

Comment: your solution worked and was the first working answer. But received another answer from @access Denied. And i think that is the perfect solution. Because assigning DataContext without MVVM pattern implementation is a work around for problem.

Comment: @maulikkansara "*Because assigning DataContext without MVVM pattern implementation is a work around for problem*" is not exactly true. It is quite common to set the DataContext of a Window to itself. *Not having* set the DataContext at all is however unusal.